# Sort an indented block of text while keeping order

Tags: python, tree

I have a block of text I need to re-arrange (using Python) which looks like this:

```
foo
    bar
        inner 1
        inner 3
        inner 2
    another
        stuff c
        stuff b
        stuff a
    more
        items z
        items x
        items y
```

And the output of this sort function must look like this

```
foo
    another
        stuff a
        stuff b
        stuff c
    bar
        inner 1
        inner 2
        inner 3
    more
        items x
        items y
        items z
```

The important details are:

- Like shown in the examples above, each new "depth" is represented with 4 spaces  . And that's consistent across the entire text.
- At each depth, the items should be sorted alphabetically. However the tree's structure must be kept the same even after sorting. So "stuff a/b/c" must always have "bar" as its parent. And "items x/y/z" must always have "more" as its parent.

Here is an attempt that came close to working but doesn't quite.

```py
import re
import textwrap

_EXPECTED_INDENTATION = "    "
_PARSER = re.compile(r"(?P<indentation>\s*)(?P<words>.+)")


def _iter_lists(item):
    if not isinstance(item, list):
        return

    yield item

    for group in item:
        for inner in _iter_lists(group):
            yield inner


def _group_by_depth(names):
    previous_depth = -1
    all_groups = []
    inner_group = []

    for depth, name in names:
        if previous_depth != -1 and depth != previous_depth:
            all_groups.append(inner_group)
            inner_group = []

        inner_group.append((depth, name))
        previous_depth = depth

    if inner_group:
        # Add the last group, just in case it was missed
        all_groups.append(inner_group)

    return all_groups


def _parse_by_depth(text):
    output = []

    for line in text.split("\n"):
        if not line.strip():
            continue

        match = _PARSER.match(line)
        count = int(match.group("indentation").count(_EXPECTED_INDENTATION))
        word = match.group("words")
        output.append((count, word))

    return output


def _sort_all(all_groups):
    for group in all_groups:
        for inner in _iter_lists(group):
            inner.sort()


def flatten_sequence(sequence):
    if not sequence:
        return sequence

    if isinstance(sequence[0], list):
        return flatten_sequence(sequence[0]) + flatten_sequence(sequence[1:])

    return sequence[:1] + flatten_sequence(sequence[1:])


def main():
    """Run the main execution of the current script."""
    text = textwrap.dedent(
        """\
        foo
            bar
                inner 1
                inner 3
                inner 2
            another
                stuff c
                stuff b
                stuff a
            more
                items z
                items x
                items y
        """
    )

    names = _parse_by_depth(text)

    # `_parse_by_depth` should generate
    # names = [
    #     (0, 'foo'),
    #         (1, 'bar'),
    #             (2, 'inner 1'),
    #             (2, 'inner 3'),
    #             (2, 'inner 2'),
    #         (1, 'another'),
    #             (2, 'stuff c'),
    #             (2, 'stuff b'),
    #             (2, 'stuff a'),
    #         (1, 'more'),
    #             (2, 'items z'),
    #             (2, 'items x'),
    #             (2, 'items y'),
    # ]

    all_groups = _group_by_depth(names)
    _sort_all(all_groups)

    flattened = flatten_sequence(all_groups)

    for depth, name in flattened:
        print("{indentation}{name}".format(indentation=_EXPECTED_INDENTATION * depth, name=name))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It doesn't work though

```
foo
    bar
        inner 1
        inner 2
        inner 3
    another
        stuff a
        stuff b
        stuff c
    more
        items x
        items y
        items z
```

because `_sort_all` would only be able to properly sort the contiguous blocks. e.g. "inner 1/2/3" and "stuff a/b/c" will be sorted correctly, but the parents such as bar, another, and more are still in the wrong order. How can I modify `_group_by_depth` and/or `_sort_all` to get the expected order?

Comment: I already made several attempts but I didn't want to post them because they're long and would make the question hard to read. And possibly would bias people's thinking towards whatever approach I used instead of the simplest answer. I also never asked for "give me code", just for a route to accomplish the task. Please request more information from the questioner if you have doubts, rather than casting doubts on the person themselves. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've modified the post with one of the more concise attempts and a question about that attempt. Please have a look and give your thoughts and offer a suggestion to solve the problem if it pleases you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this approach:

We could interpret the input as being a table with a few columns, where an indent corresponds to a jump to the next column. The columns that are skipped are assumed to have the same value as the "parent" row. We can imagine that this table has those "repeating values" removed:

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo |  |  |
| (foo) | bar |  |
| (foo) | (bar) | inner 1 |
| (foo) | (bar) | inner 3 |
| (foo) | (bar) | inner 2 |
| (foo) | another |  |
| (foo) | (another) | stuff c |
| (foo) | (another) | stuff b |
| (foo) | (another) | stuff a |
| (foo) | more |  |
| (foo) | (more) | items z |
| (foo) | (more) | items x |
| (foo) | (more) | items y |

An idea is to build this 2D list (including the repeating values), then sort that, and then convert that back to the original format.

Here is the code for that:

```
def sort_indented_text(text, spacing):
    data = []
    row = []
    for line in text.splitlines():
        stripped = line.lstrip()
        row = row[0:(len(line) - len(stripped)) // spacing] + [stripped]
        data.append(row)

    return "\n".join(
        " " * (spacing * (len(row) - 1)) + row[-1] for row in sorted(data)
    )
```

You can use it as follows:

```
text = """foo
    bar
        inner 1
        inner 3
        inner 2
    another
        stuff c
        stuff b
        stuff a
    more
        items z
        items x
        items y"""

print(sort_indented_text(text, 4))
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought about filling in the skipped columns using the same value as the parent. This solution works perfectly and is much simpler to understand, thank you so much!